# Creating a fill on grouped paths using paint bucket tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6, pen-tool

I am trying to use the live paint bucket tool on this skirt. I have grouped the whole skirt together and all the paths are closed but it isn't creating a fill.

[image]

Comment: Did you select all before going to the Live Paint tool? Did you set the gap options? Are there unexpanded path effects? Did you set some fill color before clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to find out if you have any **unopened paths**.
You can use the script below. Copy and paste it in a *Text Document* and save it as a ***JavaScript File (.js)***. Once you have the script saved you can access it from **File > Script >  Other Script ( CMD + F12 )**

Select all your paths or at least the paths that you think are not closed and then run the script. Your paths should close and you should be able to apply the fills/gradients.

CODE . **Please Keep References to Author**

```
//  ClosePts.js
//  http://www.pictrix.jp/  Umezawa
//

if (documents.length > 0 && activeDocument.pathItems.length > 0){


    myObj = activeDocument.pathItems;
    myNum = activeDocument.pathItems.length;

    for ( i = 0; i < myNum; i++ ){

        if( myObj[ i ].selected && ! myObj[ i ].closed ){

            myObj[ i ].closed = true;

        }
    }
}
```